# How to XOR Hex ByteArray Elements

Tags: python-3.x, checksum, python-bytearray

I'm trying to XOR all the elements in a bytearray, and generate the resulting checksum value in Hex. Finally, l will append the result to form a new bytearray. Sorry, I'm rusty in python now.

```
XorMath = bytearray([0x50,0x021,0x45,0x53])

Xor1 = bytearray[0] ^ bytearray[1]
Xor2 = Xor1 ^ bytearray[2]
Xor3 = Xor2 ^ bytearray[3]

checksum = hex(Xor3)
new_array = XorMath.append(checksum)

print(new_array)
```

Any way to make this more elegant?

Comment: This code doesn't work. `bytearray` is a type, not a list. Also, XorMath is a `bytearray` and you're trying to append a string to it, which makes no sense. The least any question asker should do is actually run the code they post.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk If the code ran correctly the OP likely wouldn't have asked the question in the first place. Despite all the errors, the intention of the code is at least reasonably clear if you just read it as quasi-pseudocode along with the OP's description.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk This is SO, not CodeReview. We don't ask for working code from the askers, but only that they convey what they aim to accomplish as clearly as possible and provide their best attempts. The OP did both. Anyone with a bit of programming experience and some common sense of what XOR is most often used for can immediately tell what the OP is trying to accomplish with his code, and that what he wrote was to the best of his limited abilities. Everyone started as a newbie writing "garbage" once, and not everyone progresses as quickly. So get off your high horse and be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `functools.reduce` to apply `operator.xor` cumulatively to the bytearray. The `hex` function converts an integer to a hex string, and should be called only when the value is to be displayed rather than stored in a bytearray:

```
from operator import xor
from functools import reduce

XorMath = bytearray([0x50, 0x021, 0x45, 0x53])
XorMath.append(reduce(xor, XorMath))
print(list(map(hex, XorMath)))
```

This outputs:

```
['0x50', '0x21', '0x45', '0x53', '0x67']
```